# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString method call does not change the string I call it on

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, cocoa-touch, nsstring

Inside of a for loop, I have an if statement that looks like this:

```
if([numberValues rangeOfString:@"+"].location == NSNotFound) {

    NSLog(@"Phone Number does not contain a plus sign.");

} else {

    NSLog(@"Phone number does contain a +");

    [numberValues stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"This new numberValues object should not have a + anymore: %@", numberValues);

}
```

I can confirm that the `rangeOfString:` method call works perfectly because there are phone numbers in my address book that do not start with a "+" and it will print "Phone Number does not contain a plus sign." to the log.

My problem is that the `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:` call does not work. Right after the call, when I print the `numberValues` object data to the log, the phone number still looks like this "+13997573173" instead of being printed without the plus sign like "13997573173".

I have even tried changing the "+" in the method call to something like the first 4 digits of the phone number and it still will not replace the target string with the new string.

It just prints the same value every time. Any ideas why `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:` is not working for me?

Comment: How can I see exactly who answered first? Please see the "PS" at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Hover over the "answered x minutes" ago associated with a post to see the timestamp. http://i.stack.imgur.com/8JnzV.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` actually returns a string, and does not mutate the string you've passed in.

So you likely want to do something like this instead:

```
numberValues = [numberValues stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" 
    withString:@""];
```

Comment: I'll accept in 7 minutes. Now that you answered I feel like an idiot lol. The result of the method call has to be placed inside something... I think I've been staring at my laptop for a little too long :)

Answer (score 1):

```
numberValues = [numberValues stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" 
    withString:@""];
```

`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` return a new string.assign it to origin string.

Comment: Thank you for contributing.